# Ehcache with JSONObject value

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am using ehcache. I need to put an `org.json.JSONObject` as the value of the cache.

```
cache.put(new Element("t",new JSONObject("{}")));
```

But this gives me `NotSerializableException`. Is there anyway to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Define a class extends JSONObject,and implement Serializable interface,like this:

```
public class SerializableJSONObject extends JSONObject implements Serializable   {
    public SerializableJSONObject (final String json) throws JSONException {
        super(json);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have to pass my string and convert into json object. that value is cached. so how can i do it?

Comment: You should also add constructor like JSONObject,my answer has updated.

Comment: If could help you,you'd better mark it accpeted to let others know the answer can work.